# Create a repeating vector sequence using named vector of counts

Tags: r

I have a vector, `resp` containing names, and `counts` containing counts. I want to make a vector, which repeats elements in `resp` with number of times corresponding in `counts`, and assign it to a variable `feedback`

```r
resp <- c("yes", "no", "maybe")
counts <- c(5, 10, 10)
```

Desired output

```
> feedback
 [1] "yes"    "yes"    "yes"    "yes"    "yes"    "no"     "no"     "no"     "no"     "no"     "no"     "no"    
[13] "no"     "no"     "no"     "may be" "may be" "may be" "may be" "may be" "may be" "may be" "may be" "may be"
[25] "may be"
```

I can do the following using a `for` loop:

```r
resp <- c("yes", "no", "maybe")
counts <- c(5, 10, 10)
names(counts) <- resp

feedback <- c()

for (i in 1:length(resp)){
  feedback <- c(feedback, rep(resp[i], counts[i]))
}
```

Is there a way to do this using the `apply` family of functions?

Comment: use `rep`, `feedback  <- rep(resp, counts)`

Comment: to be a bit more specific than @RonakShah: `rep( resp, times = counts )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rep( resp, times = counts)
```

Use the base function `rep`